# No network connection on a VPS

Tags: networking, debian, vps

I have a VPS hosted by OVH that run under Debian and about once a day it disconnects himself from the network. I can't ping nor I can use ssh. The problem began when I upgraded from Debian 9 to Debian 10. It's been a month that I read the logs and the journals but I can't find anything related to the network problem. I asked the support from OVH if the problem was on their side but the answered me that everything was fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Connect to host through a virtual console.

1. Check the interfaces in the system. What is the name of the interface? What is the state of the interface?

```
ip -s -s -d link show
```

2. Check the configuration of interfaces. For the `ifupdown` you should run:

```
ifquery <iface>
```

3. Try to turn down and then bring up interface with commands

```
ifdown -vv --force <iface>
ifup -vv <iface>
```

4. Fix the errors those caused.
5. Check the state of the interface and check the routing configuration:

```
ip -s -s -d link show
ip route list
```

Comment: Here the state of the interface : `ens3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000` is anything wrong ?

Comment: It's ok. Check the address and routing: `ip a ls` and `ip r ls` commands.

Comment: `default via 51.75.120.1 dev ens3
51.75.120.1 dev ens3 scope link
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17
.0.1` for ip r le and `ens3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pf
ifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether fa:16:3e:b1:4f:1b brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 51.75.123.255/32 brd 51.75.123.255 scope global dyn
amic ens3
       valid_lft 82537sec preferred_lft 82537sec
    inet6 fe80::f816:3eff:feb1:4f1b/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever` for ip a ls

Comment: seems like correct. Try to run `ping 51.75.120.1` and `ping 8.8.8.8`.

Comment: They both work. I forgot to say that my VPS is now working. I will retry these commands when the problem occurs.

Comment: Thank you. Today I tried to turn down down then turn up the interface and there was a problem with sendmail : `Can't open /usr/share/sendmail/dynamic`. I think it is due to this bug : https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=873978. I removed sendmail because I'm using postfix. In order to solve the problem I ran : `sudo apt-get --purge remove sendmail sendmail-bin sendmail-base` and I was able to turn up the interface.